# Node.js not recognizing jQuery from external file

Tags: jquery, node.js, ibm-cloud

I am attempting to push a Node.js app to Bluemix using "cf push" in the command line.  I am getting this error:

> 2016-08-13T01:18:39.89-0400 [App/0]ERR /home/vcap/app/bluemixapp.js:4
>
> 2016-08-13T01:18:39.89-0400 [App/0]ERR $('form').submit(function(e){
>
> 2016-08-13T01:18:39.89-0400 [App/0]ERR ^
>
> 2016-08-13T01:18:39.89-0400 [App/0]ERR ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It appears that the first instance of '$' is being found and is not defined.

**Node.js file**

```
var express = require('express');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var bluemixapp = require('./bluemixapp.js');
bluemixapp.main();

app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

**External JS File**

```
exports.main = function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        //Do things
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your code to the question?

Comment: Added relevant code.  Files work locally but when launched via Bluemix I receive the error.

Comment: Don't you need to assign the `$` var when you're using jQuery server-side? Something like `var $ = require('jQuery');`.